# function inside of bulk_create - List comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm doing some `bulk_create` in `Django` from uploaded `csv` file. I'm using `ignore_conflicts=True` to ignore duplicates, but it doesn't seems to work, whatever, I would like to check `duplicates` based on just one column in `csv` data. Let me explain;

My data looks like

```
name address number
aaa  bbbb    090
```

I would like to check if same `number` in database exist and if yes, don't insert the data from `bulk_create` there. 
I'm using the code bellow, but it throws an `syntax error`

```py
....some code...
all_db_data = OnlineDB.objects.all()

OnlineDB.objects.bulk_create([OnlineDB(
            number=row[2],
            name=row[0],
            address=row[1]
        ) ignore_dups(row, all_db_data ) for row in reader], ignore_conflicts=True) # reader are data from csv.reader()


def ignore_dups(row, all_db_data):
    match = all_db_data.filter(number=row[2])
    if match.Count() > 0:
        return
    return row
```

Comment: What do you try with this syntax `[OnlineDB(..) ignore_dups(..) for row in header]` ? You can't have 2 method calls

Comment: "but it doesn't seems to work" is not a valid description of your issue.